# Vertical alignment of tikz in minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, minipage, shapes

The tikz picture should be top aligned with the minipage text.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry} \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{itemsep=1pt}
    \setlist[itemize]{labelindent=\parindent, align=left, leftmargin=*, label={--}}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{pfeil}=[draw, shape=signal, signal to=south, minimum width=\textwidth, align=center, minimum height=1cm, signal pointer angle=120]

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [pfeil] (init) {Bauraum};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Verteilung der Proben in xy-Richtung im Bauraum
        \item für jeden Messpunkt mind. fünf Proben zur statistischen Absicherung oder gleichmäßige Verteilung im Bauraum
        \item Formiga P100: 200x250x330 mm
        \item P 760: 700x380x580 mm
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [pfeil] (init) {Zugproben\\bauen};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Normzugstäbe nach DIN EN ISO 3167 Typ A mit einer Gesamtlänge von 150 mm
        \item normale Refresh-Rate verwenden
        \item Welche Maschinenparameter?
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is also `\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another solution to this text structure with a `seidebyside tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry} \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{itemsep=1pt}
    \setlist[itemize]{labelindent=\parindent, align=left, leftmargin=*, label={--}}

\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\mypfeilitemize}{O{}+m+m}{
    empty, sidebyside, sidebyside align= top seam, 
    sidebyside gap=7mm, boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, 
    lefthand width=0.15\textwidth, #1}%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}\node[pfeil](init){#2};\end{tikzpicture}\tcblower#3}

\tikzset{
    pfeil/.style={draw, shape=signal, signal to=south, minimum width=\textwidth, align=center, minimum height=1cm, signal pointer angle=120}}
    
\begin{document}


\mypfeilitemize{Baraum}{\begin{itemize}
        \item Verteilung der Proben in xy-Richtung im Bauraum
        \item für jeden Messpunkt mind. fünf Proben zur statistischen Absicherung oder gleichmäßige Verteilung im Bauraum
        \item Formiga P100: 200x250x330 mm
        \item P 760: 700x380x580 mm
    \end{itemize}}
    
\mypfeilitemize{Zugproben\\bauen}{\begin{itemize}
        \item Normzugstäbe nach DIN EN ISO 3167 Typ A mit einer Gesamtlänge von 150 mm
        \item normale Refresh-Rate verwenden
        \item Welche Maschinenparameter?
    \end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `t` option of the `minipage` doesn't actually mean "the very top". It means that the baseline of the first line in the `minipage` is placed on the baseline of the line on which the `minipage` is placed. (If I have understood correctly.) This is more obvious with an example like

```
lorem \begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}foo\\bar\\baz\end{minipage}ipsum
```

So this comes down to how the `tikzpicture` is placed on the baseline. By default the bottom edge of the `tikzpicture` is placed on the baseline, so you can see that the bottom corner of the "pfeil" is aligned with the baseline of the first line in the list.

You can change that placement with the `baseline` option, which is added to the options of the `tikzpicture`. This key can take a length or a coordinate as its value, and TikZ `node`s have anchors on the baselines of the node text, so you can use for example

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(init.base)]
```

Doesn't work for multi-line nodes though, as the `base` anchor ends up on the last line of the node, so then do something like

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=\baselineskip]init.base)}]
```

If you want the very top of the node, shift the coordinate a bit, e.g. `baseline={([yshift=0.333em]init.base)}`. 0.333em is the default `inner sep` of nodes.

Unrelated comments: `\tikzstyle{foo}=[...]` is I think considered deprecated in favor of `\tikzset{foo/.style={...}}`. For typesetting numbers with units have a look at the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% to not have repeated units for things like \SI{1x2}{\m}:
\sisetup{product-units=single}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\usepackage[left=27.5mm, right=30mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{itemsep=1pt}
    \setlist[itemize]{labelindent=\parindent, align=left, leftmargin=*, label={--}}

\tikzset{
  pfeil/.style={draw, shape=signal, signal to=south, minimum width=\textwidth, align=center, minimum height=1cm, signal pointer angle=120}
  }

\begin{document}    


\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(init.base)]
%    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=0.333em]init.base)}]
        \node [pfeil] (init) {Bauraum};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Verteilung der Proben in xy-Richtung im Bauraum
        \item für jeden Messpunkt mind. fünf Proben zur statistischen Absicherung oder gleichmäßige Verteilung im Bauraum
        \item Formiga P100: \SI{200 x 250 x 330}{\mm}
        \item P 760: \SI{700x380x580}{\mm}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=\baselineskip]init.base)}]
%    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=\baselineskip+0.333em]init.base)}]
        \node [pfeil] (init) {Zugproben\\bauen};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Normzugstäbe nach DIN EN ISO 3167 Typ A mit einer Gesamtlänge von 150 mm
        \item normale Refresh-Rate verwenden
        \item Welche Maschinenparameter?
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```